# fetch only last entries using criteria(Hibernate)

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, select

I have two entities `Issue` and `Issue_Tracker`.

**Issue.java:**

```java
public class Issue implements Serializable
        {
        private Integer issue_id;
        private String  issue_description;
        private Date issue_raised_date;
        private Set<Issue_Tracker> issueTracker = new HashSet<Issue_Tracker>(0);



        @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="issue_id")
        public Set<Issue_Tracker> getIssueTracker() {
        return issueTracker;
    }

        public void setIssueTracker(Set<Issue_Tracker> issueTracker) {
        this.issueTracker = issueTracker;
```

**Issue_Tracker.java:**

```java
public class Issue_Tracker implements Serializable
{  
     private Integer   issue_id;
     private String    tracker_status;
     private Timestamp tracked_time;
```

when i left join both the table and i get following data as follows using query:

```java
SELECT issues.issue_id,
       issues.issue_description,
       issue_tracker.tracker_status,
       issue_tracker.tracked_time
FROM issues
     LEFT JOIN issue_tracker on issues.issue_id = issue_tracker.issue_id 
     WHERE issues.status = "Escalate To"
```

and output is

```java
  issue_id  tracker_status      tracked_time
    123     Assigned           1/8/2013 11:44   //1st entry
    123     Assigned           1/9/2013 11:45
    123     Completed          1/10/2013 12:52  // last entry

    32      Assigned           1/9/2013 16:46   //1st entry

    32      Assigned           1/10/2013 18:46  //last entry

    33      Assigned           1/9/2013 16:47   //1st entry

    33      Cancel             1/9/2013 17:49  //last entry
```

Now when i did these join using criteria, I get these results

```java
      issue_id  tracker_status      tracked_time
        123     Assigned           1/8/2013 11:44 //1st entry of issue_id 123
        32      Assigned           1/9/2013 16:46
        33      Assigned           1/9/2013 16:47
```

using following criteria

```java
         Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Issue.class);
         criteria.setFirstResult(from);
         criteria.setMaxResults(size);
         criteria.setFetchMode("Issue.issueTracker",FetchMode.JOIN);
         criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("status", "Escalate To"));
```

Now expected output is

```java
      issue_id  tracker_status      tracked_time
        123     Completed          1/10/2013 12:52 // last entry
        32      Assigned           1/10/2013 18:46 //last entry
        33      Cancel             1/9/2013 17:49  //last entry
```

How to achieve this, I am stuck here since last three days, any help would be great, is it happening because of this line where i am trying one to many mapping

`private Set<Issue_Tracker> issueTracker = new HashSet<Issue_Tracker>(0);`

because a **Set** does not allow duplicate values, if so what would be the possible approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT i.issue_id, i.issue_description,
       it.tracker_status, it.tracked_time
FROM issues i 
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT it.issue_id, it.tracker_status, it.tracked_time 
            FROM issue_tracker it 
            INNER JOIN (SELECT issue_id, MAX(tracked_time) tracked_time 
                        FROM issue_tracker GROUP BY issue_id
                       ) A ON it.issue_id = A.issue_id AND it.tracked_time = A.tracked_time 
          ) it ON i.issue_id = it.issue_id 
WHERE i.status = "Escalate To";
```

Comment: perfect ,thank you ,but I want this using criteria in hibernate,

Comment: how to achieve this using hibernate criteria